# How to process multi row data in test template

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

**Overview**
I have a json which feed on multiple rows and fixed columns

**Use case : Extract the value of 0222 & 0444 and 0712 & 0786   in each iteration to feed in json**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  DataDriven Test
Test Template  Create CPR Data  
*** Variables ***


*** Test Cases ***   NPA0  CARRIER0  TEL0   
scenario1  684,670,671  0222  123456789
           ...  622,670,671  0444  123456789     # This data is multirow and this is the requirement 

scenario2  633,621,652  0712  123456789
       ...  626,470,671  0786  123456789


*** Keywords ***
Create CPR Data
    [Arguments]  ${npa_row1}  ${carrier_row1}  ${tel_row1}
    ${ReqBody_PR}  set variable  {"destNums":[{"NPA":"${carrier_row1}","CARRIER":"${carrier_row2}"}]}
    log  {ReqBody_PR}
```

PS : I am not sure if it is possible through Test Template or not, just trying to get some suggestions.

Comment: So, the string "123456789  622,670,671 0444  123456789" is a single value - an argument to the template keyword, that must have a newline between "123456789" and "622"?

Comment: @TodorMinakov yes!! in layman language i want to pass 2 rows as data in each scenario and then should be able to extract each value e.g  2nd row 2nd col value i.e.  0444

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple solutions, but the most straightforward is to model the keyword based on the data.
You said all scenarios are going to have 2 rows, each with 3 elements ("columns"); in that case just make the keyword take 6 arguments:

```
*** Test Cases ***   NPA1  CARRIER1  TEL1   NPA2  CARRIER2  TEL3
scenario1  684,670,671  0222  123456789
           ...  622,670,671  0444  123456789     # This data is multirow and this is the requirement 

scenario2  633,621,652  0712  123456789
       ...  626,470,671  0786  123456789


*** Keywords ***
Create CPR Data
    [Arguments]  ${npa_row1}  ${carrier_row1}  ${tel_row1}  ${npa_row2}  ${carrier_row2}  ${tel_row3}
    ${ReqBody_PR}  set variable  {"destNums":[{"NPA":"${carrier_row1}","CARRIER":"${carrier_row2}"}]}   # in your original question, you were already referencing a variable carrier_row2 - but you haven't defined it already; now it works
    log  {ReqBody_PR}
    # you can also access now the 0222 and 0444 from scenario1 directly:
    Log    tel1: ${tel_row1} tel2: ${tel_row2}
```

---

Now, if for - reasons - you want to have a newline inside the value, you could use the `\n` character; e.g. something like

```
scenario1  684,670,671  0222  123456789\n622,670,671 0444 123456789
```

, which will be accepted by your original keyword. But - this is not a table-like data (rows & columns) - the 3rd argument will be a string, that you can split first on the newline - to get the last element of the first row, and then - on the whitespace character, to get the 3 elements of the second row.
Which is much cumbersome and error-prone; I've added the `\n` solution just for completeness, and your question included it.

Comment: option 2 : i will explore more and let you know , option 1 looks not feasible for me as sometimes i have more the 2 rows.

Comment: Well, one can craft a solution where the support is for multiple rows - as long as they are divisible by 3, or even - regardless how many columns/rows are given, if it's not really a matrix that is supplied. But I'd kindly suggest you revisit your test model - if the data is of variable length, what logic should be in the keyword to support all the variations; and is using a single template for all of them the right way to do it. My 2c.